# Link to URL in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a URL link at the end of a Flash 5.5 file that does not work. I have the following code in AS3. I do not get an error message when I save the SWF.

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
//import flash.ui.Keyboard;

var weblinkURL:String = "http://www.optiosolutions.com";

weblink_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, webLink);

function webLink(e:Event):void {
  var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(weblinkURL);
  try {
    navigateToURL(request, '_blank');
  } catch (e:Error) {
    trace("Error occurred!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running that program locally?

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code in a new Flash project, and this works as it should! Nothing seems to be wrong... So I would advice you to look at your other code...

You are sure that the button id `weblink_btn` is the correct button id of the button you suppose it to be?

One small tip:

```
import flash.events.*;
import flash.display.*;
```

It's not really needed to import with a `*`, since you are working on a KeyFrame, these imports can be forgotten. 
In general you should never import with `*`, but only the classes that are needed.

Comment: only classes that are used will be in the swf, what you import does not affect filesize. it is however wise to only import what you actually use for clarity reasons.